# Delete a record from several tables using a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

Today, 
I want to delete all test record from several tables in sql server.
Here is what I want to achieve..

```
Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0
```

Suppose this query returns 5 rows..

```
   | ID|
    ---
   | 1 |
   | 2 |
   | 3 |
   | 4 |
   | 5 |
```

Now These are the tables that I need to clean

```
delete from tmpA where ID=1
delete from tmpB where acctID=1
delete from tmpC where userID = 1
delete from tmpD where sID=1
.
.
.
delete from tmpA where ID=2
delete from tmpB where acctID=2
delete from tmpC where userID =2
delete from tmpD where sID=2
```

Can I loop through source table and extract the ID and then delete from the tables? I know I could use joins but I want to do that using While loop..

Comment: you can always write t-sql or use dynamic query.

Comment: I wonder why you say you don't want solutions with JOINs but accept a solution with EXISTS ?. They are the same for the SQL Server engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as that

```
... WHERE ID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
```

Like this:

```
delete from tmpA where ID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
delete from tmpB where acctID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
delete from tmpC where userID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
delete from tmpD where sID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
```

Comment: oops sorry for asking this question :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `WHILE` loop, you can do it like following using `WHERE EXISTS`.

```
DELETE A 
FROM   tmpa a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   sourcetable s 
               WHERE  s.accttype = 'S' 
                      AND s.acctroot <> 0 
                      AND s.id = a.id)
```

You need to do the same for other tables also.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need while loop for this

```
    delete from tmpA where ID IN (Select ID from sourceTable where acctType='S' and acctroot<>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to ensure that your ID exists on sourcetable is with an INNER JOIN.

```
DELETE T
FROM tmpA T
     INNER JOIN sourcetable S ON S.id = T.id AND S.accttype = 'S' AND S.acctroot  <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @Temp_Table Table (Id int identity(1,1),Table_Name varchar(30),Column_Name varchar(30))

insert into @Temp_Table
select 'tmpA','ID'
union all
select 'tmpB','acctID'
union all
select 'tmpC','userID'
union all
select 'tmpD','sID'

Declare @Counter int=1
        ,@Tot_Count int=0
        ,@Table_Name varchar(30)=''
        ,@Column_Name varchar(30)=''

select @Tot_Count=count(1) 
from @Temp_Table

While @Tot_Count >= @Counter
Begin

         Select @Table_Name=Table_Name
                ,@Column_Name=Column_Name
           From @Temp_Table
          Where Id=@Counter

           Exec
           (
                '
                 Delete A 
                   From '+@Table_Name+' A
             inner join sourceTable B 
                     on A.'+@Column_Name+'=B.ID
                  where B.acctType=''S'' 
                    and B.acctroot<>0
                '
           )

           Set @Counter+=1
End
```